# Shapefiles won't display with cartopy

Tags: python, shapefile, cartopy

I'm trying my first GIS project with cartopy and matplotlib and I'm having some trouble displaying some shapefiles.

The shapefiles were downloaded from here: http://data.vancouver.ca/datacatalogue/localAreaBoundary.htm

The code I'm trying to use has worked for other shapefiles but not for this set.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname = "local_area_boundary.shp"
adm1_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_geometries(adm1_shapes, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  edgecolor='black', facecolor='gray', alpha=0.5)
east = -123.0
west = -123.3
north = 49.1
south = 49.4
ax.set_extent([west, east, south, north], ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()
```

Again, I'm 100% new to GIS and cartopy (but fairly experienced in Python) and I'm sure I'm missing something easy. Any help debugging this would be great.

**Edit**: I've modified the code so the shapefile is displayed, but it now has the wrong lat/lon coordinates

```
fname = 'local_area_boundary.shp'
adm1_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())

ax.add_geometries(adm1_shapes, ccrs.Mercator(),
                  edgecolor='black', facecolor='white', alpha=0.5)
a = 483644.82757398
b = 5449579.62327763
c = 498313.01571369
d = 5460349.22564139
ax.set_extent([a,c,b,d ], ccrs.Mercator())
```

[image: Shapes are plotted but lat/lon coordinates are wrong]
I would expect the lat/lon to be centred around 49.2N/-123.1E, but instead it's 44.1N/4.3E. Can you tell if this is just bad data, or if I'm still doing the transformation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That download page is lying when it says `Coordinate system N/A`, the data is in fact projected as it has a `.prj` file which contains:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / UTM zone 10N",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26910"]]
```

So your data is in metres while your map is in degrees. So you will need to change the following lines:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
east = -123.0
west = -123.3
north = 49.1
south = 49.4
ax.set_extent([west, east, south, north], ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I assume cartopy has some way to set an ESPG code, in which case you want [EPSG:26910](http://epsg.io/26910).

Comment: This is very helpful, I didn't realize the data in the shapefile is in meters not degrees.

Comment: I've added an edit with code that fixes my original problem but the coordinates are still not correct.

Comment: Mercator is often epsg:3857 which is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah ok thanks got it! For anyone who finds this in the future, the cartopy call is `cartopy.crs.epsg(26910)` to get the projections.

Answer (score 0):

I use QGIS Explorer to open the file and read the metadata of the shapefile and found this information:

`Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 483644.83,5449579.62 : xMax,yMax 498313.02,5460349.23`

`Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

It is clear that the projection is UTM zone 10. And the extents in UTM grid units are as mentioned above.

With this information, the code is written as:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname = r"Path_to\local_area_boundary.shp"
adm1_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())
f, ax = plt.subplots()
#f.set_size_inches([10, 6])

# projection from the metadata of shapefile
# UTM(zone=10)
useproj = ccrs.UTM(10)

ax = plt.axes(projection=useproj)
ax.add_geometries(adm1_shapes, useproj,
              edgecolor='black', facecolor='gray', alpha=0.5)

choi = 1  # use either 1 or 2
if choi==1:
    # extents from the metadata of the shapefile
    # use UTM(10) grid coordinates (meters)
    west,south = 483644.83, 5449579.62
    east,north = 498313.02, 5460349.23
    ax.set_extent([west, east, south, north], useproj)
else:
    # or extents with lat long in degrees
    east = -123.0
    west = -123.3
    north = 49.1
    south = 49.4
    ax.set_extent([west, east, south, north], ccrs.Geodetic())

plt.show()
```

And the resulting plot is:

[image: output plot]

*Edit1*
Note: the coordinate display under the map is for location on the map center.